# Can't access any arrays after sorting another array

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have encountered a very strange bug:
I derive a new array `allSavings[]` from another one (`tours[]`) and sort it in the function `calculateAllSavings()`. Before I call the function I can access `tours[]` just fine, but afterwards,  I can't anymore. The div tags `demo1` and `demo2` both exist and are working fine for other outputs.

```
function euclDist(node1,node2){
    if(node1 != node2){
        var x = Math.pow(nodes[node2].x - nodes[node1].x,2);
        var y = Math.pow(nodes[node2].y - nodes[node1].y,2);
        var dist = Math.sqrt(x+y);
        return dist;
    }
    else return 0.0;
}

function tourDist(members){
    var tourDist = 0.0;
    if (members.length>1){
            for (i = 1; i < members.length; i++)
                tourDist += euclDist(members[i],members[i-1]);
    }
    return tourDist;
}

function combineTours(tourA, tourB){
    tourA.pop();
    tourB.shift();
    return tourA.concat(tourB);
}

function calculateSaving(tourA,tourB){
    var costSeparate = tourDist(tourA) + tourDist(tourB);
    var combTour = combineTours(tourA,tourB);
    var costCombined = tourDist(combTour);
    return costSeparate - costCombined;
}

function calculateAllSavings(){
    var allPossibilities = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < tours.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < tours.length; j++){
            if(i != j)
            var savingObj = {saving:calculateSaving(tours[i],tours[j]), tourA: i, tourB: j};
                allPossibilities.push(savingObj);
        }
    }
    allPossibilities.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.saving-a.saving
    })  
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "success";

    return allPossibilities;
}

//Initialize Array  
var tours = [];
tours.push([0,1,2,3,0]);
tours.push([0,4,5,6,0]);
tours.push([0,7,8,0]);
tours.push([0,9,10,0]);

//BUG
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = tours.join('\n'); // Shows array correctly
var allSavings = calculateAllSavings(); //BUG APPEARS HERE
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = tours.join('\n'); // Doesn't show anything
```

Edit Solved:
combine() was overwriting the original tours[].
by doing the combining with cloned tours, the original was left untouchted.

```
function combineTours(tourA, tourB){
    var tour1 = tourA.slice(0);
    var tour2 = tourB.slice(0);
    tour1.pop();
    tour2.shift();
    return tour1.concat(tour2);
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me

Comment: Can you please also include the code for the `tourDist` function?

Comment: Also, you should always write your if-statements with enclosing `{}` after the condition, even if it's a one-liner.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst [`If a block needs to wrap to the next line, use a curly brace. Don't use it if it doesn't.`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style#curly-braces)

Comment: @Gothdo his code does wrap (well, he intentionally puts it on the next line), thus my comment.

Comment: Thanks for the resposes. I added the methods tourDist() and euclDist(). Sorry about the bad formatting, it's kindd of hacky code for one-time use so no need for maintainability... i doubt it's the missing brackets

Comment: Just for clarification: the array that's returned from calculateAllSavings() actually works the way it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in `combineTours` function you're calling `.pop()` method on one array and `.shift()` method on another, which removes one element from each of these arrays. In `calculateAllSavings` you're calling `calculateSaving` in a loop and it's calling `combineTours`, so you're effectively removing all elements from the sub-arrays.

Maybe you should just remove these lines from `combineTours`:

```
tourA.pop();
tourB.shift();
```

For the future: use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) for debugging, it could help you identify the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response . I need pop() and shift() because every tour needs to have the number 0 in the first and last node. So if I have tourA 01230 and tourB 04560 they're supposed to be combined into  01234560.

Comment: @Samuel So call it only once on each tour.

Comment: So your answer brought me to the right path: Inside combineTours() i cloned tourA and tourB and with .slice(0) and thereby left the original tours[] untouched. Thanks a lot, i'll also edit it in the original post

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
for(var i = 0; i < tours.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < tours[i].length; j++){
            if(i != j)
            var savingObj = {saving:calculateSaving(tours[i],tours[j]), tourA: i, tourB: j};
                allPossibilities.push(savingObj);
        }
    }
```

Apart from this, you can also debug and see if your document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = tours.join('\n'); line actually gets executed. You may be running an infinite loop. Try and debug your code using chrome developer tools.

Comment: Your inner for loop should go through the outer for loop. So j should go through the first array within i, and then the second and then the third. What you were doing is, iterating the j array exactly the same as the i array. So there was no sorting happening for the internal values.

Comment: @Samuel :) You are welcome. Could you please accept my answer as well?

Comment: Sorry, but my answer was a little too quick. I was able to access tours[] again only because the statements in the j loop were never executed. This way calculateAllSavings() delivers an empty array :-(